# ObjC: Best use an NSArray or NSDictionnary for this (zBuffer)?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsarray, hashmap, nsdictionary

Say I have a collection of "node" instances. An integer property call zIndex will be used to group them.

What are the pros/cons for storing them in :
1) An array of arrays
2) A dictionary of arrays

In pseudo code, I would describe the expected result like this:

```
zBuffer[100] = [node1, node 2];
zBuffer[105] = [playerNode, collectable1];
zBuffer[110] = [foreground1, foreground2];
```

And I'm wondering about what zBuffers should be; Must NSArrays only be used for sequential read/write? Like not using non-continuous indexes?

I tried with an NSMutableArray:

```
[zBuffer objectAtIndex:zOrder]
```

But it fails if the array contains no data for that index (like out-of-bound exception).

Thanks for your advices!
J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, one of your requirements is that the indexes you use to access `zBuffer` be not contiguous (100, 105, 100). In this case, I would not use an array for that, since the indexes you can use with an array must be less than the `count` of elements of the array (if you have 3 elements, then indexes range from 0 to 2).

Instead I would use `NSMutableDictionary`, where you can use the zIndex key as a "name" for groups of objects you are looking for.

This suggestion does not take into account any other requirements that you might have, especially concerning complexity and the kind of operations you are going to carry through on your collection of nodes (beyond accessing them through zIndex).

Comment: Hey thanks for your detailed answer. It's exactly what I needed as the purpose of this zBuffer is keeping track of "batch nodes" in order to obtain the right one at runtime, when adding new nodes.

Answer (score 1):

You could actually provide both. It looks like what you want to have is a sparse array: so you look up objects by index, but it's permissible for there not to be an object at a certain index. So you could make that.

I'd do that by creating an `NSMutableArray` subclass that implements [the primitive methods documented](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Internally, your subclass would use an `NSMutableDictionary` for storage, with numbers (the "filled" indices) as keys. `-objectAtIndex:` returns either the object with that number as its key or `nil` if the array is empty at that point.

There are some ambiguities in this use of the array contract that it's up to you to decide how to address:

- does `count` return 1+(highest index in use), or the number of objects in the array?
- the enumerator and fast enumeration patterns never expect to see `nil`, so you need to come up with an enumerator that always returns an object (but lets me see what index it's at) if you want users of your class to enumerator over the array.
- you won't be able to initialise it with the `+arrayWithObjects: (id) firstObject,...` pattern of initialisers because they use `nil` as a sentinel.

Comment: Hey, very interesting idea. I'll keep this in favs. I'll do with an NSMutableDictionnary in this case!